# What type of syntax is the Java "new Type[]{...}" array literal initialization?

Tags: java, arrays, syntax, inline

What grabbed my attention, which I cannot explain to myself, is a thought about this well known code:

```
String[] str = new String[]{"a","b","c"};
```

Is `new String[]` a cast? If it is, why do we use `new` and no brackets? We would cast as in:

```
float i = (float) 3;
```

It also seem not to be a constructor, because then we would use it like a function call (e.g `new String[](...)`).

So what kind of syntax is it, and do we have more of that kind in Java?

Comment: Why do you think it can't be it's own unique syntax? Why must it fit into another category? It's not a cast.

Comment: It's simply "the syntax" for array initialization

Comment: It is an [array creation expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1).

Comment: "and do we have more of that kind in Java?" No.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax is an example of an [10.6. Array Initializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6) as part of an [15.10.1. Array Creation Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1).

> **An array initializer may be specified** in a field declaration (§8.3, §9.3) or local variable declaration (§14.4), or **as part of an array creation expression (§15.10.1), to create an array and provide some initial values**.

```
new String[]
```

is an array creation expression and

```
{"a","b","c"}
```

is an array initializer.

Since there are no dimension expression in your array creation expression (i.e. nothing inside the square brackets), there must be an array initializer:

> If there are no dimension expressions, then there must be an array initializer.
>   A newly allocated array will be initialized with the values provided by the array initializer as described in §10.6.

Answer (score 2):

It's called an [Array Initializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6), and its sole purpose, as the name suggests, is to initialize arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is related to the [array initializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6):

> **An array initializer may be specified** in a field declaration (§8.3, §9.3) or local variable declaration (§14.4), or as part of an array creation expression (§15.10.1), **to create an array and provide some initial values**.

Basically you not only create the array, but also initialize all its fields in the same instruction.

It is not a cast.

---

Note that the code:

```
String[] str = new String[]{"a","b","c"};
```

is a single command to create and initialize the array but it is also possible to use a less verbose version:

```
String[] str = {"a","b","c"};
```

Comment: Well, a cast is a part of the language too.) Otherwise it would not be compiled

Answer (score 0):

Arrays can be created in multiple ways like below, **and you are using the second one which is called the Array Initializer where you create the array while also initializing it.**

```
int[] abc = new int[3];   // This means an array of integers with size 3 is created.

int[] def = new int[]{1,2,3};   // This means an array of integers with size 3 is created and also initialized with the values 1, 2 and 3.
```

In the second statement, I am creating an array of integers with the elements as 1, 2 and 3 where the size is implicitly 3.

So, in your case `String[] str = new String[]{"a","b","c"};` , **this statement is creating an array of String values with elements "a", "b" and "c" with the implicit size of the array being 3** due to the 3 elements which it is initialized with.

Comment: I was not asking how t ocreate an array in Java

Comment: @DIBits updated the description, should be more clear now